# Navigate/Measure real objects in real space - possibly with Blender's Motion Tracking

Tags: tracking, measurement

Can Blender be used for solving such a kind of task?

Navigate a (real) small boat to the four corners of a (virtual) rectangle on a (real) water plane. The rectangle is about 300 meters long and about 50 meters wide along the water plane.

Perhaps, there is a (real) camera - static/moving, located on the bank of the water plane and streams live video into Blender. An operator navigates the driver of the boat using a radio.

This is just an idea based on what I've just seen it's possible with [Motion Tracking in Blender](https://vimeo.com/79032879).

Regards,
Jiri

Comment: Blender's motion tracking system is designed for offline tracking on recorded footage; it often requires carefully placed markers etc. and probably just wouldn't work well for real-time streamed data.

Comment: Can Blender display a composite scene - live stream from camera + (semi transparent) overlay: the 300x50m rectangle (model) inserted into a frame of the solved motion tracking task based on previously recorded footage of the same scene which is now being live streamed?

Comment: Not really, but you could pre-render the overlay with an alpha channel and overlay that on your streamed video with some other software

Comment: I see. The overlay pre-rendering can be done in Blender and composing that pre-rendered overlay image over live stream has to be done in other tool - is that correct? What tools can do the composing?

Comment: Yes. Depending on the nature of the livestream, perhaps something like [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) might be appropriate. However this is really a question for another site, perhaps [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Cool. OBS does the image overlay quite easily. Thanks! I'll get back with some kind of solution if any :-)

Comment: One more comment. Can OBS itself live broadcast the composite scene? It looks like the live broadcasting needs an external server.

Comment: All I know is OBS is often used for livestreaming to services such as [twitch](https://www.twitch.tv/), which then broadcasts the stream to viewers. Perhaps there are other ways it can be configured, but I don't know much about it.